# PHP Mail function (plain / html)

Tags: php, html, email

Good afternoon,

I have a problem with my PHP Mail function. The code works in other websites but it's not working on mine's, and there is something really weird.

When I try to send a HTML mail (text/html) I can se the **HTML tags**.
When I try to send a plain mail (text/plain) I can see **n** **r** instead of the break lines.

I have tried everything, also other solutions from Stackoverflow.com, but it's not working. It could be something realted to my server? I will have to ask to my hosting provider? It could be this?

Because I have already change it like 20 times and the code worked in other websites, but it's not working on this one.

That's my code:

```
$para = 'mymail@gmail.com'; 
$titulo = 'Title'; 
$mensaje = "Hello\r\n\r\nByeBye"; 
$cabeceras = 'From: Subject <mailing@mailing.es>' . "\r\n".'Reply-To: mailing@mailing.es' . "\r\n"; 
mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

And the results is: **HellornrnByeBye**

**Edit:**

I have tried with a different Joomla website and it worked, but when I try it in my server it didn't work, I still see the html tags...!

Thats my joomla headers (maybe there is something wrong?).

```
<head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

***I have to say that this Joomla 2.5 is inside a folder from a Joomla 1.5...!***

Thanks,

Regards,

Comment: The only thing that would cause the line breaks to show up as `\r\n` in the plain text format is that you have them encapsulated in single quotes, instead of double quotes.

Comment: Post your code in your question not in the comment box. That's what the space is provided for in the question block.

Comment: Thanks Fred, it's my first time posting in Stackoverflow.

Regards,

Comment: I tested your code and it did not show `HellornrnByeBye` it showed up correctly in Gmail. Something else is causing this.

Comment: I have also tested in a simple PHP page and it worked, but when I try to use this inside Joomla (Jumi component) it didn't worked...! Thanks, Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your content type is text/html, try using `<br />` instead of `\r\n`

EDIT:

To make a message HTML, you need to set the correct headers... as referenced [here](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Then change your mail function to...

```
mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $headers);
```

Comment: Hi Matt,

I don't have that set. I would like to make it as HTML, but I always see the HTML tags, so I tried to put plain text, but I also can see the "\n\r" tags instead of the break...!

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code and it's working outside my Joomla, but inside my Joomla (using Jumi component) is not working and I can see the tags again...! I don't know what else it could be...!